# A Rust closure that takes a trait as argument

Tags: rust

I want my function to take a closure as an argument, which takes a `PartialOrd` (or any other trait, this is just an example) as an argument and I want to be able to call that closure with a any type that implements `PartialOrd` in my function. Something along the lines of this:

```
fn my_func(cmp: fn(impl PartialOrd, impl PartialOrd) -> bool) {
    cmp(3, 5);
}
```

But of course this does not work because `impl Trait` is not valid in closure signatures. (I don't see *why* but I guess it not implemented *yet*.) So I tried something like this:

```
fn my_func<T: PartialOrd>(cmp: fn(T, T) -> bool) {
    cmp(3, 5);
}
```

This also doesn't compile because (I guess) `T` is determined by the caller and I'm just passing `i32` and it might be different that what the caller is intended to call.

So, how do I go about this? My main purpose is to do something like this:

```
fn my_func(cmp: fn(impl PartialOrd, impl PartialOrd) -> bool) {
    if some_condition {
        cmp(type1_instance, type1_instance_2);
    } else {
        cmp(type2_instance, type2_instance_2);
    }
}
```

Both `type1` and `type2` implements `PartialEq`.

To make it more concerete, I'm using `chrono` library and want to write something like this:

```
fn compare_dates(d1: DateTime, d2: DateTime, cmp: fn(impl PartialOrd, impl PartialOrd) -> bool) -> bool {
    if some_condition {
        cmp(d1, d2)
    } else {
        cmp(d1.date(), d2.date())
    }
}

compare_dates(
    Utc.date(2000 10, 11).and_hour(0,0,0),
    Utc.date(2000 10, 12).and_hour(0,0,0),
    PartialOrd::lt)
```

Note: `DateTime::date()` does not return `DateTime`, it returns a different `Date` type.

Comment: This sounds like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). Why do you want to use a generic type parameter, when you know the type is `i32`? You're kinda trying to do the opposite of what type parameters are for. The `my_func` fn doesn't decide what `T` is going to be, the caller does.

Comment: @vallentin Type is not `i32`, I described my real problem at the bottom to not fall into XY. The parameter might be one of the two different types that implements the given trait. Based on a condition I want to either call the closure with the `type1` or `type2` instances.

Comment: I noticed `type*_instance*`, but what types are they in that example? I'm saying XY problem, because you aren't really giving a concrete example of what the context and case is.

Comment: @vallentin I made an edit and used a more concrete example. Let me know if this works.

Comment: Also I want to point this out: I guess there is a way to solve my specific problem using some other methodologies but  but I'm a bit curious that if what I'm asking is possible somehow.

Comment: You can't really do that like that. Because `cmp` would only be generic in your function declaration. So when you finally call `compare_dates` then `T` would be a concrete type. You _might_ be able to do something crazy with [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html) to accomplish that. However, then you likely wouldn't be able to simply do `compare_dates(..., PartialOrd::lt)`. The easiest is likely to have 2 `cmp` fns. Do you have an example of when `cmp` would do more than just `<`?

Comment: I don't have more than two different types to compare on, so having two different `cmp` functions for each concrete types may resolve my problem as you've said, and then calling it like `compare_dates(..., PartialOrd::lt, PartialOrd::lt)`. A bit ugly but it works. If you add it as an answer I can accept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue with having a single `cmp` is that while it might be generic in the function declaration, it becomes specialized when the function is called. Thereby it cannot be used for both `DateTime` and `Date`. *(Assuming you want to avoid something even more complicated involving [`Any`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/any/trait.Any.html).)*

You can workaround this by having having two `cmp` paramters. However you can still have a single definition of your actual `cmp` function.

```rust
// chrono = "0.4.19"
use chrono::{Date, DateTime, TimeZone, Utc};

fn compare_dates<F, G>(
    d1: DateTime<Utc>,
    d2: DateTime<Utc>,
    cmp_date_times: F,
    cmp_dates: G,
) -> bool
where
    F: FnOnce(&DateTime<Utc>, &DateTime<Utc>) -> bool,
    G: FnOnce(&Date<Utc>, &Date<Utc>) -> bool,
{
    let some_condition = ...;
    if some_condition {
        cmp_date_times(&d1, &d2)
    } else {
        cmp_dates(&d1.date(), &d2.date())
    }
}
```

Now you can define a single generic `cmp` function and use it for both.

```rust
fn cmp<T: PartialOrd>(lhs: &T, rhs: &T) -> bool {
    lhs < rhs
}

compare_dates(
    Utc.ymd(2000, 10, 11).and_hms(0, 0, 0),
    Utc.ymd(2000, 10, 12).and_hms(0, 0, 0),
    cmp,
    cmp,
    // or
    // cmp::<DateTime<Utc>>,
    // cmp::<Date<Utc>>,
);
```

You can also just pass `PartialOrd::lt`.

```rust
compare_dates(
    Utc.ymd(2000, 10, 11).and_hms(0, 0, 0),
    Utc.ymd(2000, 10, 12).and_hms(0, 0, 0),
    PartialOrd::lt,
    PartialOrd::lt,
    // or
    // <DateTime<Utc> as PartialOrd>::lt,
    // <Date<Utc> as PartialOrd>::lt,
    // or
    // DateTime::<Utc>::lt,
    // Date::<Utc>::lt,
);
```

---

If you want to avoid the repeated argument, then you can define a `compare_dates!` macro as well.

```rust
macro_rules! compare_dates {
    ($d1:expr, $d2:expr, $cmp:expr $(,)?) => {
        compare_dates($d1, $d2, $cmp, $cmp)
    };
}
```

Which you then call like this:

```rust
compare_dates!(
    Utc.ymd(2000, 10, 11).and_hms(0, 0, 0),
    Utc.ymd(2000, 10, 12).and_hms(0, 0, 0),
    PartialOrd::lt,
);

compare_dates!(
    Utc.ymd(2000, 10, 11).and_hms(0, 0, 0),
    Utc.ymd(2000, 10, 12).and_hms(0, 0, 0),
    cmp,
);
```

Answer (score 3):

> But of course this does not work because impl Trait is not valid in closure signatures. (I don't see why but I guess it not implemented yet.)

I don't think it can be; this would desugar to something like

```
fn my_func(cmp: for<T1: PartialOrd, T2: PartialOrd> fn(T1, T2) -> bool) {
    cmp(3, 5);
}
```

which is not a legal type (though I just learned that using lifetime parameters in that position [*is* legal](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/subtyping.html), e.g. `for<'a> fn(&'a i32) -> &'a i32`). Also note that `T1` and `T2` would be different types, so `PartialOrd::lt` wouldn't have this type. You would instead write it explicitly without `impl`, again if it were supported in the first place:

```
fn my_func(cmp: for<T: PartialOrd> fn(T, T) -> bool) {
    cmp(3, 5);
}
```

However, another workaround is to turn the closure type into a trait and the specific closure you want into an implementation of this trait for a struct. In this case a unit struct because the closure doesn't capture anything:

```
trait Cmp {
    fn compare<T: PartialOrd>(&self, x: T, y: T) -> bool;
}

struct Lt;

impl Cmp for Lt {
    fn compare<T: PartialOrd>(&self, x: T, y: T) -> bool {
        x < y
    }
}

fn compare_dates(d1: DateTime, d2: DateTime, cmp: impl Cmp) -> bool {
    if some_condition {
        cmp.compare(d1, d2)
    } else {
        cmp.compare(d1.date(), d2.date())
    }
}
```

As you can see, you have just one `cmp` argument which plays the role of the closure, and can even be defined locally:

```
fn main() {
    struct Lt;
    
    impl Cmp for Lt {
        fn cmp<T: PartialOrd>(&self, x: T, y: T) -> bool {
            x < y
        }
    }

    println!("{}", my_func(Lt));
}
```

but is still less convenient than a closure. Whether it's a good tradeoff compared to  vallentin's answer will depend on the exact situation.